# Why can't the best resolution of graphics cards be used?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

**OS:** Windows 7
**Graphics Cards**: 2x Radeon R9 290, Crossfire Enabled.
**Manufacturer**: Diamond
**Monitors**: 2x Asus VN247 All drivers up to date as of 2/15/2015

The issue I'm having is that the max resolution that Catalyst Control Center letting me set is 1680x1050 at 60 hz. However Catalyst control center show that Maximum Reported Resolution being 1920x1080 at 75hz. I can set the max resolution using windows but then it is not using the full screen. I've tried Rolling back the drivers to an earlier version but so far have had no luck. Any advice on how to resolve this obnoxious problem?

[image: DisplayMax]
[image: ActualMax]

**EDIT** I have tried both HDMI and DVI for the connection

[image: Scaling]

Comment: There's a difference between changing the desktop resolution and the monitor resolution. The difference is there if you duplicate the screen between monitor 1 and monitor 2. It will use a common resolution that works on both. Try disable any additional monitors before setting the resolution to rule this out. If that works, see how the 2nd monitor is setup. Is it connected as duplicate? extended? or other?

Comment: They are set to be extended and are the exact same monitor with the exact same display properties.If I disable one of them the problem persists...

Comment: how do you disable them? Are you actually unplugging the cable and rebooting? In this particular case I would recommend for that option to be absolutely sure. If that doesn't work, try updating the monitor drivers (not video card drivers)

Comment: @LPChip Tried disconnecting the other monitor and the problem still persists. Looking into display drivers now.

Comment: @LPChip downloaded latest Monitor Drivers. No results.

Comment: Make sure you remove the monitor drivers through the device manager, then reboot so windows redetects the monitor drivers. I had a similar issue, and that solved it. You do not necessarily need to actually install the vendor's drivers.

Comment: I think the drivers for this card are borked and I need to revert to an older set.

Comment: Question, on your screenshot, I notice HDTV with a plus in front of it. If you unvold it, does those resolutions perhaps are there? So they are grouped? For all we know, its just hidden in plain sight. :P

Comment: @LPChip If you open and select 1080 P then it doesn't take up the full screen.

Comment: Thats weird. How is your monitor connected? Through a blue Sub-D cable? If so, hit the auto button on your display to recalibrate your screen. That might fix it.

Comment: Display 1 is connected by HDMI and display 2 is DVI. If display one is connected through DVI the card goes bonkers. Saying there is no driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using hdmi for the monitor, but even if you aren't, look through the control center for a property called overscan. Make sure the setting is 0. I have the same issue with my ati card.

If the overscan is greyed out, try setting the resolution to 1080p instead of 1920 x 1080.

Comment: I see scaling options where it show OverScan or Underscan but the scale is grayed out and can't be interacted with.

Comment: Is scaling enabled?

Comment: I've tried both enabled and disabled and neither allows me to select the desired 1680x1050. When it's enabled about an inch of the screen shows up as unusable.

Comment: How about reaching the overscan option? It looks like the overscan setting needs scaling turned on.

Comment: Adding image for to show my current options.

Comment: If you uncheck the box below overscan, does that let you change its value?

Comment: Try setting the hdmi connected display to use 1080p instead. See if that will give you the overscan option.

Comment: What did you need to do to get the overscan to not be greyed out?

Comment: Changing it too 1080P